# Issue using Taipy

Tags: error-handling, undefined, taipy, python-simplenamespace

I encoutered this bug using taipy. please kinldy help me out. this is a project I must submit by tomorrow.
The problem is on the map.py page. I am using only 2 pages. app.py(home) and map.py.
I have "traffic_category" defined but yet getting error

This is the error:
--- 3 warning(s) were found for page 'maps' in variable 'page' ---

- Warning 1: Variable 'traffic_category' is not available in either the '**main**' or '**main**' modules.
- Warning 2: Variable 'traffic_category' is not defined (in expression '{traffic_category}'): 'types.SimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'traffic_category'
- Warning 3: Cannot evaluate expression 'traffic_category': name 'traffic_category' is not defined

This was the code in the map.py page

```
import collections
import gmaps
import pandas as pd
from taipy.gui import Markdown, notify
from custom_funcs.get_data_with_coordinates import get_location

data_map = pd.read_csv('files/final_data.csv', usecols=\["date", "content","traffic_class", "place"\]).dropna()

traffic_category = "free flow"
selectors = list(data_map.traffic_class.unique())

data = get_location(data_map, traffic_category).dropna()

def display_map(data):

    # Define the center of the map
    center = (data['lat'].mean(), data['lng'].mean())
    locations=data[['lat', 'lng']]
    
    # Define the figure layout
    fig_layout = {
        'width': '800px',
        'height': '600px',
        'border': '1px solid black',
        'padding': '10px'
    }
    
    # Create the map figure
    fig = gmaps.figure(
        center=center, 
        zoom_level=12, 
        layout=fig_layout,
        map_type='HYBRID',
    )
    
    fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations))
    
    
    # Display the map
    fig

def on_change(state, var, val):
 if var == "traffic_category":
 traffic_category = val
 notify(state, f"Viewing Map for {val}")
 state.data = get_location(data_map, val).dropna()
 display_map(data)

page="""

#####Check maps here

######Check the maps for the traffic Catogories in Lagos below
<|layout|columns=1 200px|
<|
<|{traffic_category}|selector|lov={selectors}|dropdown|label=See Map|>
|>

<|
<|{traffic_category}|>
|>

|>

"""
```

Comment: Hey Lawal, Feel free to join our Discord Server discord.com/invite/SNNsCDj9? and connect with like-minded individuals and collaborate on your web application buildings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import *traffic_category* into the Script file where the `Gui.run()` is executed.

It seems like this variable is not accessible from where you call it. Importing this variable in the Script file where the `Gui.run()` is executed makes the variable, Global.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can make the map displayed. Its not displaying